# can someone explain to me why my string is not not showing in output it happens to me a lot and this is a simple example,

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, variable-assignment

can someone tell me why s is not showing up.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string a="1 23";
    string s="";
if(a[1]==' '){s[0]=a[1];

  cout<<s;  }
 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `s` is an empty string. You cannot assign something to `s[0]`

Comment: Every line of code here preserves the emptiness of `s`.  It is created empty, and no code changes its size from `0`.  See [`std::string::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allocating any character memory for `s` to refer to, so `s.size()` is 0 and thus `[0]` is out of bounds, and writing anything to it is [**undefined behavior**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) <sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1: in C++11 and later, you can safely write `'\0'` to `s[s.size()]`, but you are not doing that here.</sup>

Try this instead:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a = "1 23";
    string s = "";
    if (a[1] == ' ') {
        s += a[1];

        // alternatively:
        s = a[1];

        // alternatively:
        s.resize(1);
        s[0] = a[1];

        cout << s;
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Just note that `a[1]` is the whitespace character `' '`, so while you can assign that character to `s`, and it will print to the console, you just won't (easily) see it visually in your console.  Any of the other characters from `a` would be more visible.

Answer (score 2):

This assignment

```
if(a[1]==' '){s[0]=a[1];
```

invokes undefined behavior because the string `s` is empty and you may not use the subscript operator for an empty string to assign a value.

Instead you could write for example

```
if(a[1]==' '){s += a[1];
```

Pay attention to that in this case the string s will contain the space character. To make it visible you could write for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

//...

std::cout<< std::quoted( s ) << '\n';
```

or

```
std::cout << '\'' << s << "\'\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this is a naive attempt to parse the string. Is this what you are looking for?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a = "1 23";
    string s;
    if (a[1] == ' ') {
        s = a.substr(2);
        cout << s;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because "s" is empty string with size 0.
It means there is no element at index [0] in it.
When you ask "s" for [0] element it leads to UB.

If you want to add a[1] to "s", you can use:

```
s.push_back(a[1]);
```

Or:

```
s += a[1];
```

Or:

```
s.insert(s.begin(), a[1]); // That's bad way, dont use it.
```